# Does anyone know what this error message (from the 'readxl' package in R) means?

Tags: r, excel, namespaces, readxl

I'm trying to open an Excel worksheet in R using the 'readxl' package function 'read_excel'.

```
library(readxl)
Test <- read_excel("Test.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet1")
```

I've used the exact same bit of code on the exact same excel workbook many times over the past year, and it has never caused a problem. This time, though, I get:

```
Error: object ‘data_frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'
```

I've tried calling the file different things, moving it to different locations, opening different files etc. but am now always getting this error with the read_excel function. I can usually work out what to do in response to an error message by searching for the relevant string in Google. However, I've tried searching for this error message, and haven't found anything that looks helpful yet. If anyone has any ideas, these would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `data_frame` is relatively new to `vctrs`. You may need to update your `vctrs` package. You may have accidentally rolled back to an earlier version?

Seems it was added here:

> vctrs 0.3.3 2020-08-27

Comment: Thanks SmokeyShakers! I am not sure how I managed to roll back to a previous version of a package I've never knowingly used, but reinstalling it fixed the error! By the way, I would have upvoted your answer, but am afraid I don't have a big enough reputation, yet!

Comment: No problem! I know this one from personal experience(s).